# Avoiding buffer exceeds layer boundaries in QGIS

Tags: qgis, buffer, polygon-creation, vector-layer, boundaries

I generated random points within my map in QGIS. Then I created a buffer zone of 5km around each point because it is necessary for my analysis.

However, now the buffer zone crosses over the layer boundaries which I don't want to happen. Is there any way to avoid this? I want the buffer zones to not intersect with the layer boundaries.

[image: See the problem in the screenshot below.]

Comment: `clip` you buffers with the layer boundaries.

Comment: After creating the buffers, can you cut them using the boundary (Vector > Geoprocessing Tools > Clip)?

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

This would be a two step process.

Once you have generated the buffers you can clip them to the boundary.

This can be done with:

```
Vector > Geoprocessing Tools > Clip
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a combination of the ["Buffer"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#buffer) and ["Intersection"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoroverlay.html#intersection) within the ["Geometry by expression"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#geometry-by-expression) from the Processing Toolbox (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>).

Let's assume we have five features in *'poly_test'* (purplish) and ten in *'random_points_test'* (orange) accordingly, see image below.

[image: input]

In the "Geometry by expression" window use this formula in the *'Geometry expression'* field:

```
intersection(geom_from_wkt(
                array_to_string(
                    overlay_intersects(layer:='poly_test', expression:=geom_to_wkt($geometry))
                    )
                ),
             buffer($geometry, 150000, 50)
        )
```

[image: tool_window]

for creating buffers that do not exceed the boundary of polygons .

Press <kbd>Run</kbd> and get the output

[image: result]

Answer (score 1):

There is a possibility using a ["Virtual Layer"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#creating-virtual-layers) through `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...`

Let's assume we have five features in *'poly_test'* (purplish) and ten in *'random_points_test'* (orange) accordingly, see image below.

[image: input]

With the following query, it is possible *to create buffers that do not exceed the boundary of some polygons*.

```sql
SELECT poi.id,
       st_intersection(st_buffer(poi.geometry, 150000), poly.geometry) AS geom
FROM "random_points_test" AS poi
INNER JOIN "poly_test" AS poly ON st_within(poi.geometry, poly.geometry)
```

The output polygon layer (orange) with its attribute table will look like

[image: result]